# How to correctly apply a resource to the text of a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been following the tutorials on msdn and for some reason the application can not find my resource.

Been reading this: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

And In my application ive done this:

[image]

in the WebResource.resx ive done this:
[image]

Code in the webform:

```
<form runat="server">

       <asp:Button runat="server" Text="<%$Resource:WebResource,TimerButton %>" /> 

    </form>
```

but sadly my browser says:

> "The resource object with key 'TimerButton' was not found."

It feels like ive read the documentation 100 times but i can not see what im missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finaly found the soloution... I named my folder " App_GlobalResources folder"
instead of "App_GlobalResources"... my mistake will hopefully be some1 elses salvation.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="<%$Resource:WebResource,TimerButton %>" />
```

You have

WebResources

Comment: sorry thats a copy paste mistake on my end, you have a good eye but no thats not the problem since the code in my webform is exactly as it is in ur answer

Answer (score 0):

From the first link you have provided, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx, syntax is `<%$Resources:Class,ResourceID%>`. So your code should be:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:WebResource,TimerButton %>" />
```

**NOT**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="<%$Resource:WebResource,TimerButton %>" />
```